# How exactly is a pool mining reward distributed

Tags: mining-pools, block-reward

How is the reward distributed to the pool distributors when a new block has been found?

Two examples:

1. If my pc is connected to a pool 18 hours a day and I disconnect during
   night, will I still get a reward since I provided accepted results
   to the pool?
2. If I connect to a pool, mine for 1 day and disconnect forever. Will I participate (of course with a very low reward) if I provided some results and a new block is found by the pool after,e.g., 1 month?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the pool. Every mining pool will have a slightly different set of rules. Generally speaking they pay you on the amount of shares your miner submitted, and then do some type of formula involving the difficulty of those shares vs the rest of the pool (to determine your actual % of contribution) then once they get that %, thats what you'll get from the block reward that is shared among your fellow pool miners (after the pool takes its 1-2% pool fee).

As far as seeing a payout from mining on a pool for one day, in all of time, and never going back to it, you'll most likely get rewards for the shares you submitted, but unless you are mining with a few large rigs, one day's worth of mining may not be enough for you to get to the "payout threshold" of that pool.